# Command line argument for Query

Tags: go

I'm working on some code that's meant to dump mysql data to a .csv file. I'd like to pass in a command line arg that allows the user to input what ID is run for the query, eg. go run main.go 2 would run the query

```
SELECT * FROM table where id = 2;
```

I know that Go has the os package where I can then pass something like:

```
    args := os.Args
    if len(args) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("Supply ID")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    testID := os.Args[1]
    fmt.Println(testID)
}
```

Here's the code Im currently working on. How can I set a command line argument for the Query?

```
    rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table where id = ?;")

    err := sqltocsv.WriteFile("table.csv",rows)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    columns, _ := rows.Columns()
    count := len(columns)
    values := make([]interface{}, count)
    valuePtrs := make([]interface{}, count)

    for rows.Next() {
        for i := range columns {
            valuePtrs[i] = &values[i]
        }

        rows.Scan(valuePtrs...)

        for i, col := range columns {
            val := values[i]

            b, ok := val.([]byte)
            var v interface{}
            if ok {
                v = string(b)
            } else {
                v = val
            }

            fmt.Println(col, v)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First convert testID  to interface{} and use rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table where id = ?",testIDinterface)

Comment: Don't discard the error from `db.Query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your parameters to `Query`:

```
rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table where id = ?;", os.Args[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

testID need to be and interface{} type and add to Query

```
var testID interface{}
testID  = os.Args[1]
```

And add to Query

```
rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table where id = ?;", testID)
```

Edit:
Why interface{}?

Query function accept interface{} types in arguments. [More info](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Tx.Query)

Comment: Query accept interface{} types in arguments refer link -> https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Tx.Query

Comment: it does, and `string` is assignable to `interface{}`. (ps: downvote is not mine)

Comment: So the answer is correct, you decide to use or not interface{} type

Comment: The answer is misleading: everything in your code should have technical justification. What's the reason to not use the idiomatic `testID := os.Args[1]`?

Comment: os.Args[1] returns string type so declare and assign a variable returns a string variable. Query use interface{} type in arguments, so I declare testID like interface{} type. Declare and assign in two lines and declare and assign in one line is programmer decision. I prefer first.

Comment: You don't need `interface{}` anywhere in your code at all: `db.Query("SELECT * FROM table where id = ?;", os.Args[1])`. There are no 2 lines anywhere. You don't need _declare_ a variable in general, there is a `:=` operator.